# Integración LARAVEL, DOMPDF y QRCode (simplesoftwareio)

Tags: laravel, dompdf, qrcode

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado en Laravel 5.8 el cual cuenta con impresión de código QR en PDF; la siguiente imagen muestra las librerias que estoy utilizando:

[image: composer.json]

La idea es mostrar el código QR en el PDF para ello he creado el QR y luego  traido y enviado tal código a la libreria DOMPDF:

[image: d]

Y ésta es la vista: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claramente hay algún tipo de inconveniente el cual no sé cómo lo pueda solucionar.
Estaré muy agradecida y atenta a los comentarios.

Comment: Ufff muchas gracias. Estaba convencida de que era un problema entre librerias.. Me acabas de dar una lección. Que tengas buen día :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la documentación dice:

> QrCode Generator por defecto devolverá una imagen SVG

Pero en la etiqueta `<img>` estás pasando como MIME `'image/png'`, entonces, puedes cambiar el formato de la imagen generada a `png` agregándole `format('png')`:

```
$codigoQR = QrCode::format('png')->size(25)->generate('texto');
```

O a la inversa, dejar la imagen como se genera por defecto en `svg`, y cambiar el MIME a los datos URIs que le pasas a la etiqueta `<img>`:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,{{ base64_encode($valor) }}">
```

El punto sería hacer que coincidan los MIME type de ambos.

Enlace a la documentación de la librería **Simple QrCode**: https://www.simplesoftware.io/simple-qrcode/es/

Enlace a **Datos URIs** (MDN web docs moz://a): https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Datos_URIs

---

**UPDATE**:

Para `svg`, no necesitas que convertir los datos en base64, se puede usar `svg` puro.

Entonces puedes directamente:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8, {{ $valor }}" />
```